# How to get response message HTTP Request on Beanshell Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Hi actually I want to test web service using Jmeter. but I am stuck when I want try to get response message from http request. actually I want to get the response message from beanshell post processor. How should I do to get the response code?

Comment: the question is not very clear. can you please add what you tried (Screenshots) and what is expected?. If you want get the response message, you can use the following code "String msg = .getResponseMessage(); log.info(msg);" in BeanShell post-processor

Comment: typo in the code in above comment. try "String msg = SampleResult.getResponseMessage(); log.info(msg);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as

```
prev.getResponseMessage();
```

where `prev` is a shorthand to parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class

Demo:

[image: Beanshell Response Message Demo]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-jmeter) article for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter

Comment: thank you, it works. but I use this method to get the response message `prev.getResponseDataAsString()`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use context(ctx) variable to get the previous result data:

```
ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode();
ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseHeaders();
ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData();
```

Comment: thank you. it works too... it shoild be alternate way to get responsedata

Comment: how to get the required header from response header ?
i have 2 set-cookie values
ex:
set-cookie: _csrf=XSASEDDDS;path=/
set-cookie: X-MY-CSRF=ABcnsfdgsg;path=/